# how to stop and start execution of for loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I am creating framework for our project,

**BEFOREMETHOD** (reads first row using JXl)

```
@BeforeMethod
public void Test2() throws BiffException, IOException{
    FileInputStream filepath = new FileInputStream("D://Selenium//Project_Stage//AddGroup//inputtoAddGroup.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(filepath);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows(); 
    int rows;
    for (rows=1 ; rows < totalNoOfRows;) {
        System.out.println("BeforeMethod Executed"+rows);
        CellContent1 = sh.getCell(0, rows).getContents().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("CellContent is: "+CellContent1);
        CellContent2 = sh.getCell(1, rows).getContents();
        CellContent3 = sh.getCell(2, rows).getContents();
        CellContent4 = sh.getCell(3, rows).getContents();
        CellContent5 = sh.getCell(4, rows).getContents();
        rows=rows+1;
    }
}
```

**Test methods**

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void Test(){
    System.out.println("Test Is Executed1");
    if (CellContent1.matches("TRUE")) {
        System.out.println("p=0 Cell content is : "+CellContent5);
        cells.add(CellContent5);
    }
}
```

What I want is, for each test method there is a BeforeMethod get executed at first right, my question is I have reading first row from Excel I placed it in Before method (I need it in test method), for second row from Excel I want to read to execute second test method how should I achieve that?

If there any other way like using different loops  please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

change your iteration to the following:

```
     for (rows = 0 ; rows < totalNoOfRows; rows++) {
        for (columns = 0; columns <= 4; columns++){
            System.out.println("BeforeMethod Executed "+ rows + " " + columns);
            CellContent content =sh.getCell(columns, rows).getContents().toUpperCase();
            Test(content);

     }
        }
```

and adapt your Test method (PS: method and fieldnames should start with lower case!):

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void Test(CellContent content){
    System.out.println("Test Is Executed");
    if (content.matches("TRUE")) {
        System.out.println("Cell content is : "+ content);
        cells.add(content);
    }
}
```

Also it seems that your object CellContent is a String object. Maybe you could substitute CellContent with String.

If you specificaly want to display the row and column of your cell extend the parameters of your Test method:

```
@Test(priority=0)
    public void Test(CellContent content, int column, int row){
        System.out.println("Test Is Executed");
        if (content.matches("TRUE")) {
            System.out.println("Cell content of cell " + column + "," + row + " is : "+ content);
            cells.add(content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i have two test methods then what should i write in BeforeMethod

Comment: I dont really get what you mean. The decision is up to you what you want to do befor the Test method resolves. You could do another system.out.println after the first test and then resolve the other.

Comment: Also usually you iterate through the rows with while(sheet.getRowIterator.hasNext()) after that resolve your test method and it will be executed after every row of your document

Comment: what i want is, for each test method there is a BeforeMethod get executed right, my question is i have reading first row from excel i placed it in Before method(i need it in test method), for second row from excel i want to read to execute second test method how should i achieve that

Comment: if you want to execute first test for every first row and second test for every second row you can introduce a int counter and check your row count with if (rowcount%2 == 1){test1();}else{test2();}.

Comment: Test methods will executes 4 times because i added test notation to each test method